# Software to simulate angles in a pv system

Tags: trigonometry, angle, simulation

I am trying to model a pv system and I want to simulate different angles, and to calculate values of different angles. I am asking if there is any software that allows me to design the figure below and calculate angles.

[image: peculiar picture]

Comment: Is that some kind of planar mechanism? Try GeoGebra or other programs for interactive geometry.

Comment: I find that autocad is thé best solution but is not free